# R - Shiny App: Read in csv and convert it to a dataframe / ts object

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, time-series

I want to create a Forecast Shiny App. The user should be able to upload a csv or xls file. With the data in the file, the forecast should be done.

Since the file could be another one each time, I created a reactive read in:

```
data <- reactive ({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.table(file = file1$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header)
         })
```

To be able to further work with the data and create a simple plot, I created a dataframe:

output$plot <- renderPlot ({

```
#create dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(data())
plot(df)
```

)}

My input file is a simple csv which only contains one column with pageimpressions. The title of the column also is pageimpressions. Now the `df <- as.data.frame(t(data()))`part creates a df which looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to create a "normal" dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

AND/OR: Does anybody know how to directly create a ts object of the upper dataframe?

Many thanks in advance!

(Used packages: library(shiny))

Answer (score 0):

At least for the "normal" dataframe I'm not sure why you're running this line:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(data()))
```

`data()` is already the "normal" dataframe once it gets read into R using read.table()/read.csv(). If you run `class(data())` you should get `[1] "data.frame"`

the `t()` creates the transpose of the dataframe but it doesn't seem you're after that?

You could try `plot.ts()` or `ts.plot()`.

For ts the `xts` package is quite useful although you need some sort of time corresponding to the data points which I don't see in the dataset above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.You are right. This is a mistake. I corrected my code.

Comment: Second: I didnt include any sort of time, because the ts() package normally does it itself. At least I always could use it that way, when not using shiny. I use this code:  dailyts<- ts(df, start =c(2018,08,01), frequency = 365)

Comment: dailyts<- ts(df, start =c(2018,08,01), frequency = 365) should work with the above code. Or if you have dailyts<- ts(data(), start =c(2018,08,01), frequency = 365) and then plot(dailyts). Sorry, it's a little difficult to fully understand what your issue is.